# Compile Cocos2d-x on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, cocos2d-x

I'm just getting started using Ubuntu to develop Android project with Cocos2d-x recently.
I cloned the lastest Cocos2d-x code from GitHub, and installed the Android NDK r8.

Then I compiled `hello-jni` with no problem.
So I used `create-android-project.sh` inside by creating a test project, then success.
But when I used `./build_native.sh` compiled the project when an error.
The error is as follows:

```
Compile++ thumb  : cocosdenshion_static <= SimpleAudioEngineJni.cpp
Compile++ thumb  : cocosdenshion_static <= OpenSLEngine.cpp
/home/zhonglong/cocos2d-2.1beta3-x-2.1.0/mycocos2d/proj.android/../../CocosDenshion/android/opensl/OpenSLEngine.cpp:292:23: error: 
      expected expression
        (player->audioSrc) = {&loc_fd, &format_mime};
                         ^
```

Is that someone can help me?

Comment: did you tried this tutorial :-http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_to_run_HelloWorld_and_tests_on_linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Changing this line

```
Line 292: (player-> audioSrc) = {& loc_fd, & format_mime};
```

To this and see if it works

```
Player-> audioSrc.pLocator = & loc_fd;         : line 292
Player-> audioSrc.pFormat = & format_mime;     : line 293
```

Comment: Get problem... I import the project into eclipse and add libs/armeabi/libgame.so to build path, there is an error: Archive for required library: 'libs/armeabi/libgame.so' in project 'mycocos2d' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Comment: @kylin17  :There might be two problem with this kind of error.. First that this depends on which eclipse you using (Becoz eclipse is too buggy) ... but try one thing ...clean your whole project ..first try through command prompt/Terminal ? check wat error its showing via command prompt/Terminal   .. .Secondly your jar file must be getting installed twice ...

Comment: @kylin17 : Check my answer and  try to build it properly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654078/cocos2d-x-android-cant-resolved-coscos2dx-library/12743573#12743573

Comment: Sorry so late to reply to you, I tend to be busy. I followed your steps, and build libgame.so successed. But when I add libgame.so to my test project just gtt this error: Archive for required library: 'libs/armeabi/libgame.so' in project 'mycocos2d' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Comment: @kylin17 : Download new eclipse and then follow the proper setup it will surely run ..

Comment: I think I found the problem. My Ubuntu 12.04 is 64-bit and maybe cannot complie ndk project. Later on, I will try to use the 32-bit version and then tell you the results.

Comment: I tried 32-bit Ubuntu operation system. Now it has been working properly. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @kylin17 : your welcome nytime .. WHatever things helped you please vote it or mark it so that some one else can take further help .. Its all about passing your knowledge and helping others...