# Cocos2dx bash Error build_native.sh

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

Hello, I am new to cocos2dx. I configure cocos2dx in Windows 7 / Eclipse.  I created a project called helloworld that is running, but when I run sample project(helloCpp, testCpp) that gives an error:

```
bash /build_native.sh 
Cannot run program "bash": Launching failed
Error: Program "bash" not found in PATH
```

I have already tried [Cocos2d-x android can't resolved coscos2dx library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654078/cocos2d-x-android-cant-resolved-coscos2dx-library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe me 
I have been trying to setup cocos2dx on windows machine for about 2 weeks and I wasnt successful at all. there were lot of problems I faced still had issues to compile CPP code and othe build path issues.
Switch to MAC its easier and most of all making cross platform app windows doesnt make any sense since you cant run iOS simulator on windows machine

Comment: are you trying to compile it with correct syntax I mean its ./build_native.sh not /build_native.sh

Comment: agreed. Mac is much easier.

Comment: yes i am doing right ./build_native.sh but when i create new project using create-android-project that is running sucessfully . I think some path problem of bash but where ?

Comment: Envoirment vaiable is necessary to set that is c:/cygwin/bin

Answer (score 0):

set environment variables（c:/cygwin/bin）, then the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

All the environment variable set properly.
List of environment variable is :Android SDK path,Python and Apache Ant.
Then try to run ./build_native.sh on command promt.
Reference link:[Here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Android_with_Terminal_Installation_and_Setup)

Answer (score 0):

you Need a Proper All version

Cocos2d-x 3.6
Apache ant 
python 2.7
Eclipse 
Java

```
1.Set Java and Apache Path in Global Environment 
2.Extract cocos2d-x 3.6 Download Version
3.Open the setup.py file
4. add this all in Environment File 

COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT = 'COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT' => Here is your File where you are add
COCOS_X_ROOT = 'COCOS_X_ROOT' => you get this in Cocos2dx Folder
COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT = 'COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT'=> you get this in cocos2dx Folder
NDK_ROOT = 'NDK_ROOT' => Download NDK 9.2
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT'=> your Eclipse root
ANT_ROOT = 'ANT_ROOT' => apache ant root`enter code here`
```

add above all Proper in Environment then run into CMD, Cheers :)!